# rbindlist and nested data.table, different behavior with/without using get

Tags: r, data.table

I am loading some JSON data using `jsonlite` which is resulting in some nested data similar (in structure) to the toy `data.table` `dt` constructed below. I want to be able to use `rbindlist` to bind the nested `data.table`s together.

Setup:

```
> dt <- data.table(a=c("abc", "def", "ghi"), b=runif(3))
> dt[, c:=list(list(data.table(d=runif(4), e=runif(4))))]
> dt
     a         b            c
1: abc 0.2623218 <data.table>
2: def 0.7092507 <data.table>
3: ghi 0.2795103 <data.table>
```

Using the NSE built into `data.table`, I can do:

```
> rbindlist(dt[, c])
            d          e
 1: 0.8420476 0.26878325
 2: 0.1704087 0.59654706
 3: 0.6023655 0.42590380
 4: 0.9528841 0.06121386
 5: 0.8420476 0.26878325
 6: 0.1704087 0.59654706
 7: 0.6023655 0.42590380
 8: 0.9528841 0.06121386
 9: 0.8420476 0.26878325
10: 0.1704087 0.59654706
11: 0.6023655 0.42590380
12: 0.9528841 0.06121386
```

which is exactly what I expect/want. Furthermore, the original `dt` remains unmodified:

```
> dt
     a         b            c
1: abc 0.2623218 <data.table>
2: def 0.7092507 <data.table>
3: ghi 0.2795103 <data.table>
```

However, when manipulating the `data.table` within a function I generally want to use `get` with string column names:

```
> rbindlist(dt[, get("c")])
           V1         V2
 1: 0.8420476 0.26878325
 2: 0.1704087 0.59654706
 3: 0.6023655 0.42590380
 4: 0.9528841 0.06121386
 5: 0.8420476 0.26878325
 6: 0.1704087 0.59654706
 7: 0.6023655 0.42590380
 8: 0.9528841 0.06121386
 9: 0.8420476 0.26878325
10: 0.1704087 0.59654706
11: 0.6023655 0.42590380
12: 0.9528841 0.06121386
```

Now the column names have been lost and replaced by the default "V1" and "V2" values. Is there a way to retain the names?

In the development version (v1.9.5) the problem is worse than simply lost names though. After executing the statement: `rbindlist(dt[, get("c")])` the entire `data.table` becomes corrupt:

```
> dt
Error in FUN(X[[3L]], ...) : 
  Invalid column: it has dimensions. Can't format it. If it's the result of data.table(table()), use as.data.table(table()) instead.
```

To be clear, the lost names issue happens in both v1.9.4 (installed from CRAN) and v1.9.5 (installed from github), but the corrupt `data.table` issue seems to affect v1.9.5 only (as of today - July 8, 2015).

If I were able to stick with the NSE version of things everything runs smoothly. My issue is that sticking with the NSE version would involve writing multiple NSE functions calling each other which seems to get messy pretty fast.

Are there any (non-NSE-based) known work-arounds? Also, is this a known issue?

Comment: How about just `rbindlist(dt$"c")`?

Comment: Or more generally `var <- "c" ; rbindlist(dt[, eval(as.name(var))])`

Comment: Submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1212) will see what @Arun says. Either Way, if you won't run `get`, `rbindlist(dt[[var]])` should also work on the devel version, while it will work fine regardless of `get` on v < 1.9.5. (as mentioned by @Frank)

Comment: Thanks David. This gets me gong again.

Answer (score 0):

This must have been fixed in last 5 years since this Q was asked. Now I am getting expected results.

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.13.3 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2020-11-17 18:11:47 UTC; jan using 4 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
> dt <- data.table(a=c("abc", "def", "ghi"), b=runif(3))
> dt[, c:=list(list(data.table(d=runif(4), e=runif(4))))]
> dt
     a         b                 c
1: abc 0.2416624 <data.table[4x2]>
2: def 0.0222938 <data.table[4x2]>
3: ghi 0.3510681 <data.table[4x2]>
> rbindlist(dt[, c])
            d          e
 1: 0.5485731 0.32366420
 2: 0.5457945 0.45173251
 3: 0.6796699 0.03783026
 4: 0.4442776 0.03121024
 5: 0.5485731 0.32366420
 6: 0.5457945 0.45173251
 7: 0.6796699 0.03783026
 8: 0.4442776 0.03121024
 9: 0.5485731 0.32366420
10: 0.5457945 0.45173251
11: 0.6796699 0.03783026
12: 0.4442776 0.03121024
> rbindlist(dt[, get("c")])
            d          e
 1: 0.5485731 0.32366420
 2: 0.5457945 0.45173251
 3: 0.6796699 0.03783026
 4: 0.4442776 0.03121024
 5: 0.5485731 0.32366420
 6: 0.5457945 0.45173251
 7: 0.6796699 0.03783026
 8: 0.4442776 0.03121024
 9: 0.5485731 0.32366420
10: 0.5457945 0.45173251
11: 0.6796699 0.03783026
12: 0.4442776 0.03121024
> dt
     a         b                 c
1: abc 0.2416624 <data.table[4x2]>
2: def 0.0222938 <data.table[4x2]>
3: ghi 0.3510681 <data.table[4x2]>
```