# adding column to nested R data.table by reference

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with JSON data that gets parsed (using `jsonlite::fromJSON`) to a nested `data.frame` which I am then recursively setting to a `data.table` using `setDT`. The issue is that to "explode along" any column of nested `data.table` elements (e.g., `dt[, nested_dt[[1]], by=.(a, b, c)]`, see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296990/add-constant-column-to-nested-data-table)) it is necessary to (1) ensure all nested `data.table`s have the same columns and (2) make sure those columns have the same class.

The trouble is that there appears to be some issue with R (or perhaps `data.table`, I'm not sure) triggering a shallow copy when a new column is added to a nested `data.table`.

I'd like to do something like this (with actual logic around the added column name and type):

```
add_col1 <- function(dt) {
  if (is.data.table(dt)) 
    dt[, new_col:=NA]

  if (is.list(dt)) 
    lapply(dt, add_col1)

  return(invisible())
}
```

However testing yields

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2), b=list(data.table(d=c("a", "b"), e=c(100, 200))))
dt
#    a            b 
# 1: 1 <data.table>     
# 2: 2 <data.table> 

add_col1(dt)
# Warning messages:
# 1: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(new_col, NA)) :
#    Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table 
#    so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table 
#    has been copied by R (or been created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid 
#    key<-, names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. 
#    Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. Also, in R<=v3.0.2, 
#    list(DT1,DT2) copied the entire DT1 and DT2 (R's list() used to copy named objects); please 
#    upgrade to R>v3.0.2 if that is biting. If this message doesn't help, please report to 
#    datatable-help so the root cause can be fixed.

dt
#    a            b new_col
# 1: 1 <data.table>      NA
# 2: 2 <data.table>      NA

dt[, b]
# [[1]]
#    d   e
# 1: a 100
# 2: b 200
# 
# [[2]]
#    d   e
# 1: a 100
# 2: b 200
```

So I triggered a bad copy and didn't get the desired result (`new_col` was added to the top level `data.table` which is good, but not to the nested `data.table`s which is bad). Since I think the issue is that `lapply` isn't assigning back to the original parent `data.table` I tried:

```
add_col2 <- function(dt) {
  if (is.data.table(dt)) {
    dt[, new_col:=NA]

    id <- unlist(lapply(dt, is.list))
    for (col in colnames(dt)[id])
      dt[, c(col):=add_col2(get(col))]
  } else if (is.list(dt)) 
    return(invisible(lapply(dt, add_col2)))

  return(invisible(dt))
}
```

As shown below, this generates the desired output, but I do not avoid the shallow copy (or the warning message that comes with it).

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2), b=list(data.table(d=c("a", "b"), e=c(100, 200))))
dt
#    a            b 
# 1: 1 <data.table>     
# 2: 2 <data.table> 

add_col2(dt)
# Warning messages:
# 1: In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(new_col, NA)) :
#    Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table 
#    so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table 
#    has been copied by R (or been created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid 
#    key<-, names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. 
#    Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. Also, in R<=v3.0.2, 
#    list(DT1,DT2) copied the entire DT1 and DT2 (R's list() used to copy named objects); please 
#    upgrade to R>v3.0.2 if that is biting. If this message doesn't help, please report to 
#    datatable-help so the root cause can be fixed.

dt
#    a            b new_col
# 1: 1 <data.table>      NA
# 2: 2 <data.table>      NA

dt[, b]
# [[1]]
#    d   e new_col
# 1: a 100      NA
# 2: b 200      NA
# 
# [[2]]
#    d   e new_col
# 1: a 100      NA
# 2: b 200      NA
```

Is there a **right** way to do this? I can suppress the warning and go with the `add_col2` pattern above, but if there is a way to modify the nested data in place without taking a copy that would be great. I am also aware of the possibility of using `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE` however since my use case involves a `by=` argument I'd rather avoid that approach.

These questions were helpful for understanding but didn't solve my issue:
[Adding new columns to a data.table by-reference within a function not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078640/adding-new-columns-to-a-data-table-by-reference-within-a-function-not-always-wor)
[Using setDT inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069219/using-setdt-inside-a-function/26072152#26072152)

EDIT ------------------------

Avoiding `lapply` doesn't seem to help. The following yields exactly the same results as `add_col2`.

```
add_col3 <- function(dt) {
  if (is.data.table(dt)) {
    dt[, new_col:=NA]
    id <- unlist(lapply(dt, is.list))
    for (col in colnames(dt)[id]) {
      for (i in seq(1, dt[, .N]))
        dt[i, c(col):=.(list(add_col3(get(col)[[1]])))]
    }
  } else if (is.list(dt)) 
    stop("should not reach this now")

  return(invisible(dt))
}
```

EDIT 2 -------------------------

Per Eddi's comment below, I get the desired result with `add_col1` by adding a `setDF`/`setDT` step like so:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2), b=list(data.table(d=c("a", "b"), e=c(100, 200))))

# here is the addition
lapply(dt$b, setDF)
lapply(dt$b, setDT)

dt
#    a            b
# 1: 1 <data.table>
# 2: 2 <data.table>

add_col1(dt)
dt
#    a            b new_col
# 1: 1 <data.table>      NA
# 2: 2 <data.table>      NA

dt[, b]
# [[1]]
#    d   e new_col
# 1: a 100      NA
# 2: b 200      NA
# 
# [[2]]
#    d   e new_col
# 1: a 100      NA
# 2: b 200      NA
```

I do not understand why this step worked though. It does not appear to be because the original `dt` was formed by recycling the nested `data.table`. I got the same results using

```
dt <- data.table(a=c("abc", "def", "ghi"))
ndt1 <- data.table(d=c(1.2, 1.4), e=c("a1", "b1"))
ndt2 <- data.table(d=c(1L, 2L), e=c("a2", "b2"), f=c(1, 2))
ndt3 <- data.table(d=c(1.6, 3.4), e=c("a3", "b3"))
dt[, b:=c(list(ndt1),
          list(ndt2),
          list(ndt3))]
```

Comment: your first function isn't working for the same reason `add_col1(dt[, b])` doesn't add a `NA` column to each table in column b - you cant lapply a `:=` call

Comment: A data.table is also a list. Not sure if you want to write the first fun that way.

Comment: @Chris, understood w.r.t. `lapply` not working for `:=`. I was able to recursively `setDT` using `lapply` which was nice. In `add_col1` above the nested `data.table`s do have a column added to them (stepping through in debug mode) but those modified `data.table`s are what is triggering the shallow copy, so they don't assign back to the parent

Comment: I'd blame lapply and switch to a loop in this case.

Comment: Somehow the issue is in your original `data.table`, but I'm not sure what it is about your construction that screws it up. Your function works after doing `lapply(dt$b, setDF); lapply(dt$b, setDT)`.

Comment: @Frank is the above edit what you meant? I don't think `lapply` is causing any issues that `for ...` doesn't also cause.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're right about that. I've run into some weird things with lapply and so assumed it was the culprit.

Comment: To eddi's point, it also works if you construct your example like `dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2))[,\`:=\`(b = list(data.table(d=c("a", "b"), e = c(100, 200))))]` Maybe nested calls to data.table() don't work right?

Comment: @eddi that is really odd. Adding your line I get the desired results with `add_col1` above. I don't understand what going back and forth between `data.table` and `data.frame` did though.

Comment: I've been using v1.9.7 all along - just updated to latest version from github and got identical results.

Comment: You could post an issue on the tracker if you think it needs fixing. This seems to be enough to reproduce it `DT = data.table(d = list(data.table(a=1))); DT$d[[1]][, new_col := NA]`

Comment: I added an issue here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1629. Thanks for the concise example.

Comment: Since `data.table` is also a `list` so in both the case you will returned TRUE. The operation under `data.table` is valid while the operation under `list` is not valid for `data.table` and is throwing warning. You can use the same solution, but you can differentiate data.table and list with `"data.table" %in% class(dt)`

Comment: When `x` is a `data.table` I want both `if` expressions in `add_col1` to evaluate to `TRUE`. That controls the recursion. If you debug it you'll see that `lapply` on a `data.table` re-calls the function for each column, at which point (on the 2nd call) I have a list of `data.table` elements that I again call `lapply` on to get into each nested `data.table`.

Comment: @MattPollock what going back and forth does, is it fixes whatever is wrong (in place) since you start from a clean slate of `data.frame`, but I'm not sure what exactly is wrong to begin with

Comment: Thanks. It appears that somewhere (maybe when wrapped by `list`?) the memory address changes. `address(ndt1) != address(dt[1, b[[1]]])` in the edit 2 above